# How to copy a file to a folder if there is already a file with the same name (Linux BASH)

Tags: linux, bash

For example, if I create a dustbin folder and it has `~/dustbin/File01` already in it, how would I copy a new file into the folder with the same name?

E.g.:

```
cp ~/test/File01 ~/dustbin/File01
```

But add perhaps (Copy) to the end of it

Comment: Given the breadth of answers, I think a lot of people are confused what you're asking. Could you clarify the question? (Read some of the answers to see what needs clarifying.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unix filesystems don't allow two files with the same name in the same folder (for reference, VMS did allow that).

You can use `cat` with append:

```
cat ~/test/File01 >> ~/dustbin/File01
```

This creates the file when it doesn't exist or appends to an existing file.

Also the `cp` command offers options to make backups so it doesn't overwrite existing files. See the `--backup` option for that.

Comment: The `--backup` flag is certainly nonstandard. (My Mac doesn't have it, for one thing.)

Comment: Linux has it and the question is tagged with `Linux` :-)

Comment: GNU/Linux may have it, but I bet there are Linuxes that don't. Anyway, I've asked the OP to clarify his question because I think most of these answers are not what s/he wants.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're asking how to detect if a file already exists and then rename the new file so it doesn't overwrite. In that case:

```
if [[ -f "$HOME/dustbin/File01" ]]; then
    cp "$HOME/test/File01" "$HOME/dustbin/File01 (Copy)"
else
    cp "$HOME/test/File01" "$HOME/dustbin/File01"
fi
```

is literally what you asked for. You can do this more generally:

```
if [[ -f "$dest" ]]; then
    cp "$source" "${dest%/*}/${dest##*/} (Copy)"
else
    cp "$source" "$dest"
fi
```

But you run the risk of having "(Copy) (Copy) (Copy) (Copy) …" in your filename if you use it carelessly.

Answer (score 0):

`dd if=~/test/File01 >> ~/dustbin/File01`

Comment: I cannot set r/w block size of "cat". So I don't know how it will deal with large files. Second reason is that I sure that "dd" opens files as binary and will not stop reading at EOF character.